# embed html code code in php echo (It displays code as text)

Tags: php

I have php inside html body  like this:

```
<body>
<?php

// code from db

 $var='<a href="https://..." rel="im-checkout" data-behaviour="remote" data-style="flat" data-text="pay"></a>
    <script src="https://dqwqwqw.cloudfront.net/im-embed/im-embed.min.js"></script>';';


?>
</body>
```

I am getting html code from the database which I want to embed but it's echoing the data but not printing on the webpage.

If I type `echo '.$var.';` then code is printed as text on the page and I cannot see any html changes. How can I make it display/embed  the code?

Comment: Please direct your question to our fine manual with examples http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: Your code is a flat-out syntax error and should never display anything. `..</script>';';` will KILL the script.

Comment: Place JS in `<head></head>` for one thing and you've a quote/semi-colon as pointed out by Marc. And `echo '.$var.';` can be simplified as `echo $var;` while making sure that file is a `.php` extension and not `.html`, should it be the case.

Comment: I have removed the js code but it still echoes the text and not the html format code. How can I show the html format?

Answer (score 0):

```
$var='<a href="https://..." rel="im-checkout" data-behaviour="remote" data-style="flat" data-text="pay"></a>
<script src="https://dqwqwqw.cloudfront.net/im-embed/im-embed.min.js"></script>'; 
echo $var;
```

This should do it for now.

Comment: echo $var will print the text but does not show on html code.

Comment: make sure you dont have any additional " or ' I did test the code i posted to you it is working pretty fine. If you cant find the fault post the code you have now again pls